# Image gallery dosen't fuction properly on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Brand new to web development.

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVyhH3t49fs

Having trouble getting the  at the end of index.html to function properly, despite having copied it exactly (my 'images' folder is called 'imgs' instead). Specifically, nothing happens when I click on the numbered buttons to swap images in the gallery.

Project files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R32WhB-oWDybyNZ3NtAVRMp370QKXJiX?usp=sharing

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="./imgs/logo.png" class="logo" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Office</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hotels</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="./imgs/menu.png" class="menu-icon" />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h5>Our Products</h5>
        <h1>
          <b>Simplicity</b> <br />
          is the <b>ultimate</b> sophistication
        </h1>
      </div>
      <img src="./imgs/circle.png" class="small-icon1" />
      <img src="./imgs/circle.png" class="small-icon2" />
      <img src="./imgs/square.png" class="small-icon3" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" class="col-right">
      <div class="gallery-box">
        <img src="./imgs/pic2.jpg" id="gallery" />
        <ul>
          <li class="btn">01</li>
          <li class="btn active">02</li>
          <li class="btn">03</li>
          <li class="btn">04</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="./imgs/circle.png" class="small-icon4" />
  <img src="./imgs/square.png" class="small-icon5" />
</div>
<script>
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
  var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

  var imgs = new Array(
    'imgs/pic1.jpg',
    'imgs/pic2.jpg',
    'imgs/pic3.jpg',
    'imgs/pic4.jpg',
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < btn.legnth; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function () {
      gallery.src = imgs[i];
      let current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace('active', '');
      this.className += 'active';
    };
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be apprecaited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading you code and find the mistake. You write 'length' wrong in the loop. Here how te right code looks like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function () {
      gallery.src = imgs[i];
      let current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace('active', '');
      this.className += 'active';
    };
  }
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help you